# How to initialize a Python class constant?

Tags: python, class

How can a Python class constant be initialized once, and shared across instances? This is the line of thinking:

```
class X():
    # initialize a constant that will be used by all instances
    with open("list_of_valid_words.txt", "r") as f:
        VALID_WORDS = [ a.strip() for a in f.readlines() ]

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
    def valid_object(self):
        if self.var in VALID_WORDS: return True
        else: return False

a = X("this")
a.valid_object()
NameError: name 'VALID_WORDS' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class method to initialize the shared variable:

```
class X():
    @classmethod
    def class_init(cls):
        with open("list_of_valid_words.txt", "r") as f:
            cls.VALID_WORDS = [ a.strip() for a in f.readlines() ]

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
        
    def valid_object(self):
        if self.var in self.VALID_WORDS: return True
        else: return False

X.class_init()
```

Now we can instantiate objects and test them:

```
a = X("word")
a.valid_object()
True
```

Comment: Try `self.VALID_WORDS` directly - you don't have to use that `class_init`.

Comment: Thank you @iBug. Some people recommend pulling the class object via cls=self.__class__ do you have a view on this? Is it purely stylistic?